# Highlight div when radio button checked

Tags: jquery, html

guys how to create a addclass and removeclass in jquery? I just want to create a **active** class name under the div when radio button selected? I attached the picture below for some example.

[image]

Comment: we need html and your code effort?

Comment: please share the html or a jsfiddle

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This will add the `active` class to the containing DIV, and remove it from all the other DIVs around it.

```js
$(":radio").click(function() {
  $(this).closest("div").addClass("active").
  siblings("div.active").removeClass("active");
});
```

```css
.active {
  background-color: hotpink;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <input type="radio" name="radio">Button 1</div>
<div>
  <input type="radio" name="radio">Button 2</div>
<div>
  <input type="radio" name="radio">Button 3</div>
```